# R ffdfdply reset cumsum using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Sorry for asking basic question. I am using ff package and used `read.csv.ffdf` to import the data. I have more then 50 million rows in excel and I want to do cumulative sum on one of the column and reset it when it finds 0. I have the below code to generate cumulative series and but don't know how to access the current row.

```
idx <- ffdforder(i[c("a","c","b")])
ordered_i <- i[idx, ]
ordered_i$key_a_c_d <- ikey(ordered_i[c("a", "c","d")])

cumsum_i <- ffdfdply(ordered_i, split=as.character(ordered_i$key_a_c_d), FUN= function(x) {
    x <- as.data.table(x)
if(x[**current row**, d]==0)
{
    result <- x[,cumsum_a_c_d :=0]
}
else
{
    result <- x[, cumsum_a_c_d := cumsum(d), by = list(key_a_c_d)]
}
    as.data.frame(result)
}, trace=T)
```

I am using the `data.table`package to get the cumulative sum done. How can I access the current row in data table so that I can compare it with 0 and reset the cumsum. I need the expected output as shown below. It's the cumulative sum of column d.

```
a   b   c   d   Result
1   1   1   1   1
1   4   1   0   0
1   6   1   1   1
1   2   1   1   2
1   5   1   0   0
1   3   1   1   1
```

Thanks

Comment: It is better to rephrase your question as this is a question related to data.table syntax, not related to ffdfdply, nor read.csv.ffdf.

Comment: I gave ref to read.csv.ffdf and ffdfply just because folks knows beforehand that I am using ff package. It can be easily done through ddply function but finding it difficult through ffdfdply function.

Comment: The 'x' argument to FUN will be a data.frame, possibly with multiple rows. What do you mean by 'current row'? Also, without your source data it's difficult to interpret what you're expecting from the results. It'd be great if you could mock up a small example.