# R reset cumsum when it found 0

Tags: r

I am using the `ff` package to load an excel file.

```
i=as.ffdf(data.frame(a=c(1,1,1,1,1,1), b=c(1,4,6,2,5,3), c=c(1,1,1,1,1,1), d=c(1,0,1,1,0,1)))
```

I am trying to get the cumulative sum on column d and reset it whenever it found 0. I am trying to get the below output.

```
a   b   c   d   Result
1   1   1   1   1
1   4   1   0   0
1   6   1   1   1
1   2   1   1   2
1   5   1   0   0
1   3   1   1   1
```

I know, I can easily achieved it through `ddply` but I have large set of `data rows i.e. > 5000000 rows.`

Thanks

Comment: will d be always 0/1 data?

Comment: Also, it's good practice to edit [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17884128/r-ffdfdply-reset-cumsum-using-data-table) rather than repost.

Comment: `@EDi`, yes its always 0/1 data. `@Arun`, Soultion you provided is working for small set of data. I am getting memory error `cannot allocate vector of size 93.0 Mb`. I am working on more than `> 5000000` rows `@Thomas`, ok..will take care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work but little bit slower with 24385601 rows. I created unique combination on column a and c and use the `Arun` solution. Key column (key_a_c) is used to split the data set i.e. to reset cumsum.

```
Create a unique key on column a and c
    i$key_a_c <- ikey(i[c("a", "c")])

Generate cumulative series by spliting on the basis of key_a_c
    p1=ffdfdply(i, split=as.character(i$key_a_c), FUN= function(x) {
        x$Result <- as.ff(x[, "d"] * sequence(rle(x[, "d"])$lengths))
        as.data.frame(x)
    }, trace=T)
```

Please share your views and code if you have some optimized solution.